# Write to file Failed - VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am having trouble getting this script to work on Windows 8. It works on Windows 7 and lower. When I run it, it tells me write to file failed, line 32 char 7(start of line). The objective is to pull a zip file from our server and place it in the folder stated in ExtractTo.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
user=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")
comp=oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ComputerName%")

Dim objShell
Dim Documents

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Documents = objShell.Namespace("MyDocuments")

strFileURL = "http://www.markettraders.com/downloads/UCS-Indicators/Active-Scalper/Active-Scalper.zip"

strHDLocation = Documents & "\Ultimate Charting\Custom indicators\Active-Scalper.zip"


Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, fal
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objADOStream.Position = 0

    objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
    objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

ZipFile= Documents & "\Ultimate Charting\Custom indicators\Active-Scalper.zip"

ExtractTo = Documents &  "\Ultimate Charting\Custom indicators\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If NOT fso.FolderExists(ExtractTo) Then
    fso.CreateFolder(ExtractTo)
End If

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).items
objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(ZipFile) Then
    fso.DeleteFile(ZipFile)
End If

WScript.Echo "Your custom indicator has been added!"
Wscript.quit
```

Comment: In windows 8 MyDocuments  replaced with Documents - this is the problem

Comment: @Yuri No. The problem is that the [`Namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method doesn't work that way. Not on Windows 8, and not on any earlier version. So it clearly isn't possible that the code posted in the question has ever worked anywhere.

Comment: Can it be replaced with Documents = objShell.SpecialFolders("Documents")
?

Comment: @Yuri Not exactly. `Shell.Application` objects don't have that method. But `WScript.Shell` objects do. This would work: `Documents = oShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")`.

Comment: objShell.Namespace does work. It is working properly now and I haven't changed that line.

Comment: `Set Documents = objShell.Namespace("MyDocuments")` can't possibly work. It leaves `Documents` with the value `Nothing` and the subsequent `strHDLocation = Documents & "\Ultimate Chart..."` fails with an "object variable not set" error. I'm [not making this up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Ansgarwiechers I actually changed that line to - FullPath = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments"). Most likely why it is working. I'm assuming if I changed it back, this script wouldn't work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably trying to read the response before it's ready. You need to check the `readyState` property to see if the request has completed (status = 4).

```
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 And objXMLHTTP.readyState = 4 Then
```

But you've got two major things happening on one line, so to help yourself debug your issue, split your statement up a bit and guard against obvious exceptions:

```
s = objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody

If Len(s) > 0 Then
    objADOStream.Write s
End If
```

Then rerun your script and see where your error occurs.

Comment: `objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false` opens an asynchronous HTTP GET request, `objXMLHTTP.send` sends the request. The call does not return until the request is complete. At that point the `status` property holds the HTTP status code of the request. Checking for `ReadyState = 4` is required for Internet Explorer objects, but not here.

Comment: The ReadyState = 4 actually made it work. The only thing that irks me now is for some reason I have to run it twice on Windows 8 for it to work. It'll error out the first time, and then the second time it will work properly. Any ideas on why this may be?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think you meant to say it opens a _synchronous_ request.

Comment: @Bond Indeed I did. I blame it on the wine ... 9///9

Comment: @Bryan That's only possible if you actually have `objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, fal` instead of `objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false` in your code. The `fal` would then be interpreted as an uninitialized (empty) variable, so the `open` method would use the default value for the `async` parameter (`True`).

Comment: You guys are great! Thanks for the input. This had me flustered!